# Hook when a product post is edited

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried several unsuccessful ways to get a hook option when the post product only is edited not added, I'm using woocommerce.
Here is my main attempt.

```
add_action( 'updated_product_meta', 'my_product_edited');

function my_product_edited( $post ) {

    if ($post->post_type == "product") {
        $productId = $post->ID;

        $args = array (
            'search' => 'myusername'
        );

        // The User Query
        $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

        // The User Loop
        if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {

            global $post;

            $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
            $tld_prod_url = esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) );
            $subject = "Product Updated Notification";

            foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {

                $to = $user->user_email;
                $body .= "The following product was updated: \n\n" . $post_title . "\n" . $tld_prod_url . "\n\nThanks" ;

                wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body );
            }

        } 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The hook is named `post_updated`:

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'my_product_edited', 10, 3);

function my_product_edited( $post_id, $post_after, $post_before ) {

   // $post_after : Post as it is saved now in the DB    
   // $post_before : Post as it was before the update
}
```

See [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/).

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am receiving emails every time I do any type of editing in the post. I need to receive the notification only after I click the update button. Thanks.

Comment: That's hard ... You could inject jQuery code to the wp-admin edit page, executing an additional AJAX request "onclick". Instead, you could define which properties need to have changed in order for the email to be generated, comparing `$post_after` and `$post_before`.